# VBS or BAT script for opening WMI ports in windows firewall

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, wmi, netsh, windows-firewall

How can you most reliable open ports need by WMI in windows firewall ? In need this in form of a BAT or VBS script and it needs to work on win XP and all newer.

Thank you very much.

EDIT1: win XP insted of 2000.

Comment: Windows 2000 doesn't have a built-in firewall.

Comment: OK, my bad. I thought they get it with latter service packs.

Comment: No, it comes with XP SP2 (maybe SP1, but I don't think so). It wasn't ported as far back as Windows 2000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.BAT**

You can use the [`netsh`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true) command to open a specified port in the firewall. to use the wmi you must run something like this.

to allow remote administration

```
netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable
```

and to open the WMI port

```
netsh firewall add portopening protocol=tcp port=135 name=DCOM_WMIPort
```

Additionally you can read this article [`Connecting WMI Through Windows Firewall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**VbScript**

if you want to use  vbScript to accomplish this task , try using the [`HNetCfg.FwMgr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845%28WS.10%29.aspx)COM object in this article [`Windows Firewall Scripting`](http://www.activxperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/networking/windowsfirewall/) you can found a serie of samples to manage the firewall settings using this com object from VbScript.

Comment: Just one more question. How can you determine wheter firewall is on or off ?

Comment: using the `HNetCfg.FwMgr` com object and VbScript, you can try this `Set objFirewall = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")
Set objPolicy = objFirewall.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile 
wscript.echo "is my firewall is enabled " & objPolicy.FirewallEnabled
`

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there a way to chek firewall status using netsh ?

Answer (score 0):

Although JScript wasn't mentioned by name, JScript is available from Windows 95 throughout all Windows OS's and uses the same WSH as VBScript.

You can create a .js file and use this code:

```
//Open WMI and Remote Access Ports
var firewall = new ActiveXObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr");
var policy = firewall.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
var admin = policy.RemoteAdminSettings;
admin.Enabled = true;
```

You can then execute this .js file the same way you would execute any .vbs file.